# Выражения "ёксель-моксель", "ёшкин кот"

Tags: эвфемизм

Когда примерно появились эти выражения? *Ёлки-палки* раньше появилось, если да, то когда?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Когда" ответить как правило невозможно. Такие междометия-эвфемизмы появляются и исчезают как грибы после дождя. Но брошу свои пять копеек.

**Ёшкин кот**

Выражение древнее, первоисточник - в народе, явно не из фильма "Любовь и голуби".

Самое раннее из нацкорпуса.

> ― стерла кровь и застучала по лестнице, на бегу оправляя подол. ― Ну,
> Веруся, ёшкин кот, ― сказал Петрович. ― Принимай. Он уже стоял у
> правой дверцы, помогая Гоше выбраться из машины.
> .....
> ― Вагон-то с сортировки не подали, ёшкин кот, ― вступился Петрович с таким
> выражением, будто это именно он был виноват, что не подали с
> сортировки вагон. [Андрей Волос. Путевка на целину (1954) // «Новый Мир», 2003]

Что касается этмологии... От "Яга" было бы "Ежкин" (иногда, кстати, так и пишут).
Поэтому возведение к тому самому коту Баюну несколько сомнительно.

**Ёксель-моксель**
Тоже не ново под Луной. Помню, что в 65-м или 66-м году я его видел на 16 полосе "Литературки" (клуб 12 стульев) без претензии на какую-то новизну. Там он был еще и "фасованный".
Первоисточник, возможно, в псевдо-морских ругательствах (***Бом-брам-стаксель мне в брамсель!***)

Comment: Спасибо, интересно! Радует, что они давно существуют, как мне и казалось. Подумал, что, наверно, даже "ёлки-палки" возникло не до революции, и, по всей видимости, это подтверждается: самый старый пример в Нацкорпусе 1923 года — вскоре после революции.